# Twitter Bootstrap with asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am developing a web application with asp.net webforms with full time server side controls, can I use twitter bootstrap with webforms to make the application responsive. I did work on html5 and responsive web apps with asp.net MVC through client side coding. I am confused can I use twitter bootstrap with webforms in which all the controls are rendering dynamically.

Comment: yes, you can, twitter bootstrap is mainly use for responsive design and grid layout and off course can use server side controls with twitter bootstrap cssclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also a nice article to begin:

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-3-0-0-with-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: hi, do you know if we could use [pure](http://purecss.io/) can be used with web-forms?

Comment: Yes, you can use any of the front-end frameworks like  pure,foundation,zimit,ink, etc but you won't be able to use 'Design View' in Visual Studio. You will have to work in 'Code View'in Visual Studio and probably will have to do minor tweaking sometimes. Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Devexpress offers native [webforms for bootstrap controls](https://demos.devexpress.com/Bootstrap/GridView/) as well.